# Angular - Navigating to named state from Interceptor

Tags: angularjs, routes

```
This my main module definition:
$rootScope.$on('unauthorized', function () {       
    $state.go('login');
});
.config(
function ($stateProvider, $logProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
    // main application area //
    $stateProvider
        .state('body', {
            url: '/',
            template: '<div ui-view />'
        });
    $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController',
    });
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('APIInterceptor');
 });
```

Interceptor definition:

```
service('APIInterceptor', function($rootScope) {
    // Just for testing
     $rootScope.$broadcast('unauthorized');
}
```

It's not following this:
$state.go('login'); and seems like it's looping until Chrome fails the page. Without $state.go('login'); code runs ok but I need to open the login page on unauthorized. My question is how do I navigate to login state?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$rootScope.$on('unauthorized', function ($state) {       
    $state.go('login');
});
```

Comment: After modifying code: TypeError: $state.go is not a function

Comment: Did you include $state  in your Controller ?
`angular.module('yourApp', [])
.controller('YourController', function($scope,$state) {
$rootScope.$on('unauthorized', function(){
    $state.go('login');
}
}`

Comment: Yes, I did include it.

Comment: @FaouziCaptivo - Welcome to Stack Overflow.  While code-only answers are perfectly acceptable here, your answer would be more useful for people coming in the future if you could add some explanation.  Perhaps something explaining what correction was made, and how your code fixes the problem that the OP was having.